# Adjust for correlation within group in linear mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to use a linear mixed model for this experimental setup: Students are tested three times, before and after a lecture, and after a pause, at two occasions. I want to test whether age and quality of sleep affect their score in addition to the timing of the test (testTime; before, after, pause), but also the effect of time between the tests. So my model is

```
score ~ testTime + age + sleep + time + (1|subjectID)
```

However, I wonder how to take into account that the scores within one day will be correlated, so that compund symmetry cannot be assumed? I have tried the `nlme` package in R with the syntax

```
mod2 <- lme(score ~ testTime + age + sleep + time, data = df,
            random = ~ 1 | subjectID, correlation = corCompSymm(fixed = FALSE))
```

but it seems to only take into account the random effect. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Does each subject always have all 3 tests on the same day ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, Robert! All subjects had their three tests on different days, but the three tests of that subject were always done at the same day (subject 1 had three tests on monday, subject 2 on tuesday and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RobertLong pointed out, it is important to know if the tests were administrated on the same day. If yes, then you cannot distinguish between the `day` grouping factor and the `subjectID` grouping factor. If however the tests were administrated on different days, then you could consider a more elaborate random effects design/model. This is more easily fitted in `lmer()` from package **lme4**. E.g., you could use something along these lines:

```
lmer(score ~ testTime + age + sleep + time + (1 | subjectID) + (1 | Day), data = df)
```

where `Day` is the variable in `df` identifying on which day the test was given.

Comment: Thank you, Dimitris, for a nice solution! The tests were administrated on the same day for each student, but the students were tested at different days (student 1 had three tests monday, student 2 three tests on tuesday, and so on), I assume that is what you meant with "administrated on different days"?